# inotifywait usage and exclude

Tags: regular-expressions, inotify, exclude

I want to monitor special path to any event of create or modified files recursively in it via **inotifywait** but I don't know what's my problem is.

I have some folders that I want to exclude.

```
watchpath
    ->  folder1
        -> file1
        -> ingnorefile1 [IGNORE]
    ->  ignorefolder1 [IGNORE]
```

How do I correctly exclude them using a regular expression?

```
inotifywait -mr --exclude '(ignorefolder1|folder1\/ingnorefile1)' -e modify -e create -e delete . | while read date time dir file; do
```

What is correct regular expression to use to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4):

Correct regexp: `(ignorefolder1|folder1/ingnorefile1)`. But your expression works too.

Using a backslash to escape a non-metacharacter is an error.  "/" is not a metacharacter and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: when i create some files in **ignorefolder1** event send.

Comment: when i create some files in ignorefolder1 event not send. i run `inotifywait -mr --exclude '(ignorefolder1|folder1/ingnorefile1)' -e modify -e create -e delete . ` and `echo foo > ignorefolder1/bar`